# BAM external cassandra

Tags: cassandra, wso2, wso2-bam

I would like to use Cassandra with WSO2 BAM. BAM is coming out of the box cassandra db however I want to use external Cassandra Server. Is there any way to use external cassandra.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can point WSO2 BAM to a external Cassandra Cluster using $CARBON_HOME/repocitory/conf/etc/cassandra-component.xml.

https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/branches/4.0.0/products/bam2/2.0.1/modules/distributed-setup/cassandra-component.xml

You can give more than one host in the Nodes section. Use comma to separate host:port entries.