# embedded cassandra in WSO2 BAM 2.0

Tags: cassandra, wso2, wso2-bam, embedded-cassandra

How to disable embedded cassandra comes with WSO2 BAM. I should not be able to connect to it from Cassandra explorer using localhost:9160

I would like to configure it to external clustered cassandra instance as per article - 
[BAM external cassandra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12798855/bam-external-cassandra)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start the server with following system property to disable startup.

```
sh wso2server.sh -Ddisable.cassandra.server.startup=true
```